# how to select all checkbox with Master checkbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have 1 Top Master select box, which (de)activates Master 1 and Master 2 checkboxes. And Master 1 and 2 can (de)activates each 4 Slave checkboxes. I use here ng-model and ng-checked.

e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="top" ng-model="master1"/> Master 1
```

My question:

1. When TOP Master is selected, why are the slaves of Master 1 and
   Master 2 not selected, although their ng-model (Master 1 and Master
   2) are selected? When I select Master 1 or Master 2, their slaves
   will be selected.
2. If 4 slaves are selected, the Master of them should be also selected. When both Masters are selected, then TOP Master should be selected. How can I realize it? With which controller?

Please check my code on Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aF2aL/32/

Answer (score -1):

you need to change ng-checked="master1" to  ng-checked="(master1||top)&&master1"

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="top"/> Top Master
   <ul> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="top" ng-model="master1"/> Master 1  
        <ul ng-repeat="slave in slaveOne"> 
              <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="(master1||top)&&master1"/>{{slave.name}} 
        </ul>
    </ul>

  <ul>  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="top" ng-model="master2"/> Master 2  
        <ul ng-repeat="slave in slaveTwo"> 
            <input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="(master2||top)&&master2"/> {{slave.name}}
      </ul> 
  </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, at first it will work. But do as follow: 
Select slave 1.1 then Master 1, then you will see, you cannot unselect slave 1.1, when you use TOP Master.